# Complex string match SPSS (v20)

Tags: arrays, string, string-comparison, spss

I got a problem I cant figure out using SPSS (v20).

There is a master list with 10.000 strings. Think of it as an array like so:
['Sao Paolo S.P.', 'IDE MUNICH', '1_New YORK', 'BabylonX', ...]

I have a dataset with a variable, that contains strings **similar** to the beforementioned array, but that are not the exact same ones.

Like so:

[image]

What I need to do is: check if OldString (from the dataset) is part of any of the strings in the master array.

Obviously **123 Babylon** (from the dataset) will be related to **BabylonX** (from the array).

Obviously **1234 Sao Paolo S** (from the dataset) will be related to **Sao Paolo S.P.** (from the array).

and so on...

If a match is detected, then the string from the (master)array should be filled in in a new variable NewString.

Is there any way to achieve that? Using VBA, Perl, PHP this is dead easy, but using SPSS I got no clue how to combine those steps.

Comment: re "is similar to or part of", well `char.index(stringa, stringb)` will do "part of", but how do you define "similar to"? If you have a working example in VBA, Perl, or PHP you can add it to your post so we can try to apply it to SPSS.

Comment: probably true. so "part of" might be sufficient. however I still need to figure out the hard part of putting char.index in a loop that actually fills stringb... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax is a possible way to do loop the match comparison using `char.index`.

```
*First I'm turning your master list into a dataset - 
this can be done differently depending how the data is 
stored right now. In this example I just copy-pasted 
from your post into the syntax.

data list free/masterstring (a20).
begin data 
'Sao Paolo S.P.', 'IDE MUNICH', '1_New YORK', 'BabylonX'
end data.

*now I create a new syntax with a comparison command for each string in the list.

cd "c:\your path".
string cmd (a100).
compute cmd=concat("if char.index('",lower(rtrim(masterstring)),"', 
    lower(rtrim(mystring)))>0 matchedstr='",rtrim(masterstring),"'.").
write out="check strings.sps"/cmd.

* the syntax is ready, at this point you will go back to your original dataset. 
For the example I'm creating a small example dataset.

data list free/mystring (a20).
begin data 
"123 Babylon" "babylon" "Sao Paolo" "1234 Sao Paolo S" 
end data.

*now we can run the syntax created earlier on the present dataset.
string matchedstr (a50).
insert file="check strings.sps".
exe.
```

What you should see in the result is that "babylon" was recognized as part of "BabylonX" (the command equalizes lower/upper cases) and therefore "BabylonX" appears in the `matchedstring`. The same for "Sao Paolo" and "Sao Paolo S.P.".

Note: if `mystring` matches more than one string in the list, the present syntax will only capture the last match.